# MySQL Query - How to order the results in a certain way

Tags: php, mysql, database, sorting

Below is a preview of what I have so far:

[image]

**MySQL Table:**

[image]

What I want to do is be able to sort this in a certain way.  I would like for all rows that are "FREE" to be at the very top, so where special_price is equal to 0.00.

I also would like all rows with a special to be after that, and then all rows with just a normal price would be after that.  Is there any way to do that without specifying a sort_id so the user wouldn't have to change the order themselves?

So in the above example, the last field "Testing" would be moved up one, and "Replace Air Filter" would be last.

Right now in my query there is no ORDER BY, so it is ordering by the id.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(special_price,99999) ASC, price ASC
```

should do the trick.

#### Explaination

`COALESCE` is a function that takes the first non-null value, so anywhere you have a null special price, it will default to `99999` (just some arbitrary high number to get it at the end of the ordering). From there we order on price, so any ties, as well as the end of the list, will be in ascending order by price.

Comment: Plugged it in and it works perfectly! Do you mind explaining it a little bit just so I can learn and understand for the future?  Thank you so much.

Comment: Doesn't `ORDER BY` expect a column?

Comment: It's my understanding that MySQL can't use an index to sort values returned by functions. If there were a large number of rows to sort this could be very slow. I'm curious if there's a way to do this without `COALESCE()`?

Comment: @rdlowrey It's true, this can't be index sorted, which is a problem. But unfortunately there really isn't an easy way to sort it otherwise, since nulls will end up at the top of the `ASC` sort, which is what we want last. And @Drew, I added an explanation for you

Comment: +1 didn't think of using coalesce.  I was in the middle of solution using CASE WHEN when I saw your post.  Nice.

Comment: Try it. Put some records into your table (you can write a small script, that will do it for you) and run the queries against it, for example via "MySQL Query Browser". For example you can use my query (;)) to have something you can compare the results against. Additional you should test it with different table sizes, for example 10000, 50000, 100000, 500000. Then you should be able to decide, if the results are ok for what you expect will be your table size.

Comment: @Drew Depends on how much it is until you care about it affecting performance. I used this on a query that got back usually around 1000+ items and I was still around 0.1 seconds if I remember correctly. If you're returning millions, or even probably over 5000 of records, this is not going to be a good query for you. Resisted the over 9000 joke there, but that would probably also be less performant. But, again, it all depends on what it is being used for and how quick it needs to be.

Comment: Oh ok, because I will only be displaying 8 of these per user so the query will have a LIMIT 8 on it.  there might be 5,000 of them in the database but the QUERY will only be showing at max 8 so this should be fine!

Comment: @Drew The `LIMIT` will be applied after the `COALESCE`, so the important number will be how many are in the database (or really are returned by the rest of the query). But even still, I don't think 5000 records would be bad. And if it gets too long (~0.5 seconds+), you can always load it via AJAX since it sounds like it might be a web app.

Comment: If I understand it right the `LIMIT` does not affect the performance of the query here, because MySQL needs to create the full result table, before it can cut it down to the desired number of records. As a sidenote: Cache the result :) Because it doesn't look like it will change every minute.

Comment: oh okay. thanks for explaining this to me I appreciate it.  but the query will still have WHERE user_id = ?  so total records for each user will be around 8 still. but TOTAL with every user could be thousands.

Comment: @Drew Then it should perform really well. Having the `WHERE` filter that knocks it down that much means this is probably your best bet

Answer (score 1):

You can combine two selects with `UNION`

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `special_price` IS NOT NULL ORDER BY `special_price` ASC,`price` ASC;
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `special_price` IS NULL ORDER BY `price` ASC;
```

I don't know, how this behaves from the performance point of view, but as far as I know this is just like two simple queries, with the small overhead from `UNION`.

Minor update: Because both queries *cannot* return the same records the default behaviour `UNION DISTINCT` is not required and I hope, that `UNION ALL` is just a little bit more performant.

Comment: This is also a good way to do it, and might end up with better performance for larger datasets than mine is. +1

Comment: @Ktash - yeah, I'm curious about the performance of the two methods as well.  I think it will come down to how the table is indexed.  It would be my guess that special_price is not indexed (and probably should not be).  If that is true, then coalesce is only doing one complete pass of the table while the union is doing two complete passes.  However, this is just a guess without building it and examining the explain plan.

Answer (score 1):

Using a function return value to sort the results can be very slow if you are sorting a large number of rows because MySQL can't use an index to sort these values. So how to get around this?

If an item *MUST* be on special to be free (which seems to be the case from the table layout image you provided) you could try:

```
SELECT *, special_price IS NULL AS not_special
FROM tablename
ORDER BY not_special ASC, special_price ASC, price ASC;
```

This adds an extra column to the results that equals 0 if the item is on special, 1 if not. We then put all the "special" items at the top of the sort and sort by ascending special price and price.

This will allow you to avoid the overhead of `UNION`, still use an index for the sort operation and avoid very slow queries when sorting a large number of rows with a function return value ... but only if an item must be on special to be free.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY CASE special_price
        WHEN '0.00' THEN 1
        WHEN null THEN 3
        ELSE 2
    END
```